# Virtual friend functions and template explicit specializations

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I'm trying to simulate the effect of a virtual friend function by using a protected virtual member function (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.3).
In addition, I use explicit specializations for my templated classes. I was wondering if somebody could shed some light to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Below, I'm posting the code with the compiler errors. Any suggestions are welcomed!

#### foo.h

```
template < class T, class U >
class CFoo;

template < class T, class U >
void applyOnBar( const CFoo<T, U> &, const CBar<U> );

template < class T, class U >
class CFoo{

    public:
        .....
        friend void applyOnBar< >( const CFoo<T, U> &, const CBar<U> & ); // error, line 28: function does not match any template declaration.
        .....
        virtual ~CFoo();

    protected:

        virtual void do_applyOnBar(const CBar<U> &);
        .....
};
```

#### foo.cpp

```
template < class T, class U >
void applyOnBar( const CFoo<T, U> & refFoo, const CBar<U> & refBar ){
    refFoo.do_applyOnBar(refBar); // error, line 36: passing argument first argument discards qualifiers.
}

template < class T, class U >
void CFoo<T, U>::do_applyOnBar( const CBar<U> & refBar ){  // error, line 40: member function is protected.
    ......
}
#include "../impl/foo-impl.inc"
```

#### foo-impl.inc

```
template class CFoo<float, float>; // line #1
.....
template void applyOnBar(const CFoo<float, float> &, const CBar<float> &); // line #6

./inc/foo.h: In instantiation of ‘CFoo<float, float>’:  
./src/../impl/foo-impl.inc:1:   instantiated from here  
./inc/foo.h:28: error: template-id ‘applyOnBar<>’ for ‘void applyOnBar(const CFoo<float, float>&, const CBar<float>&)’ does not match any template declaration  

./src/foo.cpp: In function ‘void applyOnBar(const CFoo<T, U>&, const CBar<U>&) [with T = float, U = float]’:  
./src/../impl/foo-impl.inc:6:   instantiated from here  
./src/foo.cpp:40: error: ‘void CFoo<T, U>::do_applyOnBar(const CBar<U>&) [with T = float, U = float]’ is protected  
./src/foo.cpp:36: error: within this context  
./src/foo.cpp:36: error: passing ‘const CFoo<float, float>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void CFoo<T, U>::do_applyOnBar(const CBar<U>&) [with T = float, U = float]’ discards qualifiers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template < class T, class U > void applyOnBar( const CFoo<T, U> &, const CBar<U> );
```

That lacks an & on the second argument, should be:

```
template < class T, class U > void applyOnBar( const CFoo<T, U> &, const CBar<U> & );
```

Next,

```
virtual void do_applyOnBar(const CBar<U> &);
```

This one needs a const, since you use `refFoo.do_applyOnBar(refBar);` with refFoo being const.

```
virtual void do_applyOnBar(const CBar<U> &) const;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
refFoo.do_applyOnBar(refBar); // error
```

Since `refFoo` is a reference to `const CFoo`, so it cannot be used to call non-const function. `do_applyOnBar` is a non-const member function.

So either you make `d_applyOnBar` a const-function, by writing the keyword `const` on the right side of function signature, or make `refFoo` non-const by removing the `const` qualifier in the parameter declaration!

The other problem is pointed out by Erik. See his answer!

Comment: @Javier: Did it solve your problem? You need more help and clarification?

Comment: @Nawaz, I didn't need to change the type arguments of the templates. Why do you think that this is needed?

Comment: @Javier: Are you talking about X and Y names of type argument? or const-ness of CFoo?

Comment: I don't think you do, that would make all instantiations a friend. You only need to friend it for your own type.

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm referring to `X` and `Y` typenames.

Comment: @Javier: I removed that part. Actually I misunderstood your post.

Comment: @Nawaz, to understand it better, the `applyOnBar` method has two constant reference parameters. This means, that the objects can't be changed inside of the function. At the same time, it means, that the `non-const` objects could also have been passed as parameters to this method, right? Now, why does the method `do_applyOnBar` need also to be `const`? Is it because the `const-ness` get propagated throughout the whole code, right? And therefore, since `refFoo` is a `const object`, we need to guarantee that it's not going to be changed inside of the `do_applyOnBar` or any other method, right?